# Run several Powershell scripts and confirm completion

Tags: powershell

I have written the below to execute a number of `PowerShell` scripts and append the results to a log file. At the moment there are only two examples, but it will eventually contain over twenty.

```
$LogFileLocation="G:\ReportTesting\"
."G:\Powershell\PowershellFunctions.ps1"

$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$error.clear()
try
    {
    & "$ScriptPath\large_gains.ps1"
    }
    catch
    {
    Log-File-Append ("$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) ERROR: Large_Gains report execution failed")
    }
if (!$error)
    {
    Log-File-Append ("$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) INFO: Large_Gains report execution succesfully completed")
    }

$error.clear()
try
    {
    & "$ScriptPath\large_losses.ps1"
    }
    catch
    { 
    Log-File-Append ("$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) ERROR: Large_Losses report execution failed")
    }
if (!$error) 
    {
    Log-File-Append ("$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) INFO: Large_Losses report execution succesfully completed")
    }
```

The issue is the underlying scripts are very large and throw various non-terminating errors. This results in each script completing, but the log file being appended with the error message.

Is there a way to catch only errors that physically stop a script completing?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want the child scripts to terminate on all errors? Just on particular errors? If so, what would constitute errors that you'd consider terminate-worthy? Should the parent script continue even after a child script failed? Or should it terminate as well?

Comment: The parent script should continue even after a child script fails (which it does). What I'm looking for is just to catch any errors where the child script completely fails.

Comment: Define "completely fails". What constitutes a "complete failure" of either child script? For child scripts to terminate on any error you can set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, but the question doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the types of errors that the other scripts throw. try this for more Error information

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. They become useless when the link target vanishes for whatever reason. Include the relevant content in addition to posting the link.